# using jQuery to add a class of active to navigation items when the corresponding page div is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

So I'm very much a jQuery noob and I don't know whether the following is possible - at least as I'm thinking of it - or how to do it.

**The current setup**

http://joelglovier.com
So I have a one page mini-site with a fixed navigation at the top of the screen. All (but one) of the navigation elements simply scroll the user down to the corresponding div down the page. I have that all set up just fine.

**What I want to do...**

I want to use jQuery to add a class of "active" to the list item anchors when they are positioned over their respective div on the page. Preferably it would not use the click function, so that even users who simply scroll down the page without clicking on the nav elements to get their would experience the same thing. Similar to the [phpfog home page](https://phpfog.com/).

I peeked at the way phpfog.com has it setup and from what I could see it's using some type of calculation with the window selector to apply the class, but A) I don't completely understand what it's doing or how to build something similar, and B) I don't know if they are doing it in the most straightforward manner.

I wrote out what I want to accomplish in a plain english statement, since I don't have a mastery on jQuery enough yet to write it out in a syntax:

> If .section-link is in the window on the
>   href value of same id, add class of
>   "active"

So here's the code I have *(HTML only, the CSS is irrelevant bc I already know how I want to style it, just want to add the active class at the appropriate place)*:

```
<div id="site-nav">

<div class="wrap">

    <ul id="nav-links">

        <li class="section-title-nav top">
            <h4><a href="#jag-home" class="section-link scroll">Home</a></h4>
        </li>

        <li class="section-title-nav skills">
            <h4><a href="#background-section" class="section-link scroll">Background</a></h4>
        </li>

        <li class="section-title-nav projects">
            <h4><a href="#projects-section" class="section-link scroll">Projects</a></h4>
        </li>

        <li class="section-title-nav blog">
            <h4><a href="http://blog.joelglovier.com" class="section-link">Blog</a></h4>
        </li>

        <li class="section-title-nav random">
            <h4><a href="#random-section" class="section-link scroll">Random</a></h4>
        </li>

        <li class="section-title-nav credits">
            <h4><a href="#credits-section" class="section-link scroll">Credits</a></h4>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>

</div>
```

And further down the page, sections that are linked to in the nav are marked up about like this:

```
<div id="random-section" class="main-section wrap clearfix">

    <h2 class="section-title"><span class="bg">Random</span></h2>
    <span class="section-title-border"></span>

    <h2 class="coming-soon">COMING SOON</h2>

</div><!--/#random-section-->
```

So, and tips on how to accomplish this, or whether I'm thinking about it the wrong way is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example I put together; I will be the first to admit it can be improved but it might give you a decent starting point to work from.

**http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/KMwhZ/1/**

---

The basic idea is to listen for `scroll` events on the window and then, for each navigation link, extract the `href` value and check if the corresponding element is visible or not. If it is, then it's link is selected and the previously highlighted element is deselected. I'm breaking early when the first visible section is found, you can get slightly different behaviour by going all the way through the list.

My example breaks when the divs are small enough in `height` that multiple divs are visible when the page is scrolled all the way to the bottom - in the case, the links for the lowest few divs will never get hightlighted. But that appears to be the case even with the phpfog page you linked to - the links for `Testimonials` and `Free Tools` never get activated because my display is tall enough to show the last 3 sections when scrolled all the way down. Note that this *won't* be the case if *don't* break early - there, the last visible section will be highlighted. But you can then see the opposite problem - the top section's link is never activated since something else is always visible.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for breaking this down so well. Since I'm such a noob I will have to take time to really understand what you are doing. Do you mind if I take your code and use it or build on it?

Comment: Also, why don't you have a $ sign at the beginning of your script to initiate jQuery?

Comment: @JAG2007 Oh sure, that's what I posted it for - feel free to do whatever you'd like with it. As for initializing jQuery, the example is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which provides the environment for various JS libraries/frameworks. If you look at the side bar on the left, you'll see a drop down menu that is set to `onLoad` by default - this is the event in which the JS gets wrapped - if you look at the source of the Result frame, you'll see my JS has been set into `$(window).load()` and jsFiddle takes care of loading jQuery.

Comment: So, of course, when you're using this on your pages, you'll need to do all of that work yourself, using either `$(document).ready()` or any other way to ensure that your code only runs when the environment you need is properly available (such as the DOM being ready or all images being loaded etc).

Comment: Okay, cool...so I tried adding it and it doesn't seem to be working. Any tips?

Comment: OK, so it turns out it IS working properly! I just didn't have my CSS rules written properly to make the effect happen like I thought it should.

Comment: Only part missing is that it only adds the "active" class when the link is clicked, not if the user is just scrolling over that section. That's where I was hoping I can write a statement that says something like, "if the .nav bar is positioned on XX div, highlight the .nav-link with that corresponding href value".

Comment: @JAG2007, I played with your site a bit and I think I've found the problems - the first is that you've adapted my self-executing function to `$.ready()` but haven't removed the trailing `()`, making it of the form `$(document).ready(function highlightNav(){})();` which breaks stuff. You should get rid of those.

Comment: The second is a mix of two things - if you look at my JS code, you'll see that I have a `return false;` where the `active` class is being set in order to break early. Now you have your first nav link set to `#jag-home`. Unfortunately, this is the id for the `body` which means that it is *always* visible. This combined with the breaking early on finding the first match means that my JS always highlights the link for `TOP` and doesn't look any further. You can fix this in two ways - 1. Comment out or delete the `return false` in my script. 2. Change your HTML to move the `jag-home` id elsewhere.

Comment: Commenting out the `return false` seems simpler and it doesn't really make much of a difference in terms of the highlighting so I'd suggest doing that first and seeing if you're happy enough with the results and avoid having to change your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); 
    $("#navbar li a").each(function() {//alert('dsfgsdgfd');
    if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
    $(this).addClass("active");}
});`enter code here`
}); 
</script>
```